# How can I add a new folder in Sublime Text?

Tags: sublimetext

I'm in *Sublime* working on a project that I need to add a folder in; when I right click to try "Add Folder.." I type in name, press enter and nothing happens. It will still allow me to add a file no problem, but that's not what I need just yet.

Comment: Do you have a project or directory (folder) open in Sublime?  If you do, you can add a new folder to it by control-clicking an existing folder and selecting `New Folder...` in the sidebar, however if you just have one file open, Sublime wouldn't know where to put the folder you're adding.  If you want to open your current directory from the terminal in Sublime, you can do so with `$ subl .`.

Comment: I do have an existing project folder open and I did do that and it doesn't add. thats the issue I am having :/

Comment: See if restarting Sublime helps.  I've experienced a few bugs in the sidebar over the years that are fixed with an app restart.

Comment: If restarting doesn't do it, one more place you can try is the [Sublime Forum](https://forum.sublimetext.com/).  They have a technical support section specifically.  One other thing I forgot to mention is that sometimes installing packages can conflict with each other.  If you have recently installed multiple packages that modify the side bar, you may try disabling them one by one.

Comment: Just to clarify your question in my head, are you trying to add an existing folder to the list of folders that are open or create a whole new folder?

Answer (score 6):

You can add files and folders on the sidebar in Sublime Text. First, go to Project -> Add Folder to Project and select whatever your parent folder is. That'll put your parent folder in the sidebar. Then you can right click on any of the folders in the sidebar to create child files and folders.

Comment: Note that if you wanna create a folder the new name must be followed by /, otherwise you will end up creating a file!

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problems, not being able to create folders in the sidebar. Luckily, this method worked for me: 
I typed in the name field the full path of one random file: 
foldername-1/foldername/filename.php
The folders got created automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I had the same issue, but I've realised that when you click on create New Folder, appears a bar at the bottom asking you for the Folder Name. Once you give it a name, the folder will be added.

Answer (score 0):

I may have the same problem with you.
When I press Enter, it actually gives me a newline.
I can't apply the rename/add folder action through sidebar.

[This github issue may be related.](https://github.com/sublimehq/sublime_text/issues/2876)